# How to Create Graph for Concurrent Projects

Tags: sharepoint, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a list of projects from SharePoint which has one column for Start Date, and one column for End Date. I would like to create a Power BI visual which plots for all dates in a calendar how many projects are currently being worked on.

I have done something similar to this in SAS, and even Excel, where I can just have an arbitrary number of columns, representing a date, and then create an if statement referencing that date which gives a binary value for whether or not that date is in the desired interval. Then I can add those up and plot the totals against the aforementioned dates. As far as I have been able to do, I cannot replicate this in Power BI. Is there some sort of functionality or custom visual I do not know of which could achieve this?

Comment: Can you show what your data looks like and what your SAS result that you'd like to replicate looks like? There's not sufficient detail in your question to elicit a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following using the following 'pseudo' code.

1. First create a New Table from the modeling tab and use the following code to create a small calendar table.

[image: Modeling tab]

```
Calendar = 
    CALENDAR ( 
        MIN ( Projects[StartDate] ) , 
        MAX ( Projects[EndDate] ) 
    )
```

2. Create a measure from the same menu as where you created the table and add the following code

```
ActiveProjects = 
var _selectedDate = MIN ('Calendar'[Date] )

RETURN
    CALCULATE ( 
        COUNTROWS ( Projects ) ,
        ALL ( Projects ) ,
        Projects[StartDate] < _selectedDate ,
        Projects[EndDate] >= _selectedDate
    )
```

3. Then plot the Date field from your calendar table against the measure you've just created and create an area chart for instance.

[image: Data fields]

[image]

Comment: It can be any name. I agree my example might be a bit confusing in that manner, I'll change the measure name.

Comment: Is there any way to include a status with this, so that it could be sliceable? For example, each project could be in progress, not started, or completed. It would be great if you could filter the visualization based on that parameter. If this is out of scope, I completely understand.

Comment: Assuming that the status is an additional field in your dataset, you can replace ```ALL( projects )``` with ```ALLEXCEPT( projects )``` and add the status as a category to your visual.